# Strange thing in the early "building a ROS package" tutorial

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running ROS Indigo under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I am following the tutorials (beginner level), with quite no deviations.

At this point of [this tutorial about packages](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages) instructions say:

> You should see that there is a folder
> called beginner_tutorials which you
> created with catkin_create_pkg in the
> previous tutorial. We can now build
> that package using catkin_make:
>
> ```
> $ catkin_make
> ```
>
> You should see a lot of output from
> cmake and them make, which should be
> similar to this:

What I should obtain for the tutorial is a long list of sentences.
But what I obtain is a shorter list

```
Base path: /home/marcor/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/marcor/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/marcor/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/marcor/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/marcor/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/marcor/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/marcor/catkin_ws/build"
####
```

But no errors message. I continued to follow the tutorials with no problem at all. But today it seems I have not properly created the package beginner_tutorials. But ROS tutorials page have no explanation of this fact (the listed code is the only difference). What I made wrong? Thank you all in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247360/strange-thing-in-the-early-%22building-a-ros-package%22-tutorial/) by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2016-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it from myself. I started again all tutorials from zero (creating catkin ws) and I managed to obtain full compilation of my package: maybe I was wrong in some part of it. For the second issue (package not found) I discovered I have to write `source ./devel/setup.bash` in every new terminal before the `roscd` command into the workspace

---

Originally posted by [marcoresk](https://answers.ros.org/users/28398/marcoresk/) with karma: 76 on 2016-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0